# How to submit different models that derive from the same base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, inheritance, form-submit, model-binding

I'm trying to use a single `@Html.BeginForm()` and a single `Create` action in the controller.  But both in the view and the controller action, my models are abstract classes. So I need to somehow create the derived class in the view's Form according to the user's selections, and send it to the controller through the base class, to later catch it in the controller action by checking the base model's type, like

```
if(baseModel is derived1)
{}
else if(baseModel is derived2)
{}
```

I tried casting the model in the editor, like

```
   <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => ((YagliBoya)model).En) (cm)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => ((YagliBoya)model).En)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => ((YagliBoya)model).En)
    </div>
```

but it doesn't work, and what's worse is, the form tries to submit the base class, which then throws "Cannot create abstract class" exception. How can I extend these?

Comment: halo, are you sure you aren't creating a problem in order to solve it?? if the only common feature of the two models is the base class and all else varies, i'd be tempted to just give them their own views and be done with it and move on the the rest of the project, otherwise you risk a maintenence nightmare, should a 3rd/4th  subclass enter the equation. but hey. that's just me, Mr SRP :)

Comment: you might be correct, but i'll give CustomModelBinders a shot, and see where it goes